# Add a element with listener within react element

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, contenteditable

I am working on creating a contenteditable div and change elements to wrap some part of text typed by user into a span or p with a on click listener and show a new pop on hover.Right now I am doing something like this

```

```
onChange(event) {
        console.log(event.target.value);
        this.setState({
            body: event.target.value
        });
        event.target.value = event.target.value.replace('you', '<span class="green">you</span>')
        this.html.innerHTML = '<span>'+ event.target.value + '</span>';
    }

    onChangeDiv(event) {
        this.setState({
            body: this.html.innerText
        })
    }  
    return (
        <div>
            <div spellCheck="false" contentEditable ref={(input) => {this.html = input}} onInput={this.onChangeDiv} onBlur={this.onBlur} ></div>
            <textarea placeholder="Start Typing" spellCheck="false" onChange={this.onChange} value={this.state.body}></textarea>
        </div>
    );
```

in the on change method is there way to replace the 'you' with a React component or add a event listener to render a new div

Comment: i also need a on click listener for this span. For e.g. a Component <NewSpan onClick={this.clickNewSpan} />

Comment: so why not just create an element and add a listener to it and insert it into the desired element?

Comment: all this should happen programmatically after api call that determines particular words

Comment: also i want to replace just few words with a span like "you" in how are you with a <span>you</span>